# How to Iterating Through APIs with Multiple Pages?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am pulling list of **audiences** from api.
Important thing to note is only about **10 audiences per page shows**. In other words, I have to **iterate through multiple pages** in order to view/check information for all the audiences.
How to do this?

Here is how this pulling list from api looks now:

Audience list component.ts:

```
export class NanoAudienceListComponent implements OnInit {

public audienceListDto: AudienceListDto;
public audienceListDtoData: AudienceListDtoData;

constructor(private audienceModel: AudienceModel,
            private modalModel: ModalModel) {
}

public ngOnInit() {
    this.getListDto();
    this.getListDtoData();
}

private getListDto(): void {
    this.audienceListDto = this.audienceModel.getListDto();
}

private getListDtoData(): void {
    this.audienceModel
        .getListDtoData(this.audienceListDto)
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
}
```

}

Audience Model in which we send api req:

```
    @Injectable()
    export class AudienceModel extends AbstractEntityModel {

    public static ENTITY_NAME: string = 'audience';

    public dto: { [key: string]: AudienceDto };
    public dtoList: Array<AudienceDto>;

    protected entityName = 'Audience';
    protected list: AudienceListDto | null = null;

    protected service: AudienceService;

    constructor(audienceService: AudienceService) {
        super(dialogModel, notificationModel, audienceService, errorHandler);
    }

    public getListDtoDataFromApiByEntity(audienceListDto: AudienceListDto): Promise<any[]> {
        return this.service.getList();
    }
}
```

Audience Service:

```
export class AudienceService { 
public getList(...args): Promise<any> {
    return this.http
        .get(this.listUrl, {headers: this.requestHeaders.getHeaders()})
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response.json());
}
```

}

List component html:

```
 <nano-table *ngIf="audienceListDto.isLoaded === true"
            [@fadeIn]="'in'"
            [tableList]="audienceListDto.list"
            [columnsArray]="columnsArray"
            [pageCount]="10"
            [sortField]="'latestGeneralUploadUniqueUsers'"
            [sortInverse]="true">
    <ng-template let-audienceListDtoData="item">
        <div class="nano-table-entity-name-cell">
            <span [tooltip]="audienceListDtoData.name"
                  [routerLink]="['/private/audience/' + audienceListDtoData.id]"
                  class="nano-c-p">
                {{ audienceListDtoData.name }}
            </span>
            <span>
                {{ audienceListDtoData.id }}
            </span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span [hidden]="audienceListDto.areStatisticsLoaded === false">
                {{ audienceListDtoData.dateRange }}
            </span>
        </div>
```

Table Component ts: (this comp is called on List component and they have parent child relationshp)

```
export class NanoTableComponent {

@ContentChild(TemplateRef) template: TemplateRef<any>;

@Input() columnsArray: Array<NanoTableHeader> = [];
@Input() isAsync: boolean = false;
@Input() nanoTable: NanoTable;
@Input() pageCount: number = 10;
@Input() pageCountOptions: Array<number> = [5, 10, 20];
@Input() sortField: string | null = null;
@Input() sortInverse: boolean = false;
@Input() useQueryParams: boolean = true;
@Input() hasExport: boolean = false;


@Input()
public set tableList(value: Array<any>) {
    this._tableList = value;
    this.onTableListChange();
}

public get tableList(): Array<any> {
    return this._tableList;
}

@Output() paginationChange = new EventEmitter();
@Output() exportRequest = new EventEmitter();

public isExportInProgress: boolean = false;
public isLoadingAsync: boolean = false;

public pageNumber: number = 1;
public searchWord: string = '';

private _tableList: Array<any> = [];

constructor(private router: Router,
            private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
}

public getFilteredList() {
    if (this.isAsync === true) {
        return this._tableList.slice(0, this.pageCount);
    }
    if (this.pageNumber > Math.ceil(this.filterListBySearchWord().length / this.pageCount)) {
        this.pageNumber = 1;
    }
    return this.filterListBySearchWord().slice((this.pageNumber - 1) * this.pageCount, (this.pageNumber - 1) * this.pageCount + this.pageCount);
    // TODO: Change this.
}

public getLengthForFooter(): number {
    if (this.isAsync) {
        return this.nanoTable.total;
    } else {
        if (this.searchWord) {
            return this.filterListBySearchWord().length;
        }
        return this.tableList.length;
    }
}

public exportReport(): void {
    this.isExportInProgress = true;
    this.exportRequest.emit();
}

public onPageCountChange(pageCount: number): void {
    if (this.isAsync === false) {
        this.pageCount = pageCount;
        // this.filterList();
    } else {
        this.nanoTable.pageCount = pageCount;
    }
    this.onPaginationChange();
}

public onPageNumberChange(pageNumber: number): void {
    if (this.isAsync === false) {
        this.pageNumber = pageNumber;
        // this.filterList();
    } else {
        this.nanoTable.pageNumber = pageNumber;
    }
    this.onPaginationChange();
}

public onSortFieldChange(sortFiled: string) {
    if (this.isAsync === false) {
        this.sortField = sortFiled;
        if (this.sortField === sortFiled) {
            this.sortInverse = !this.sortInverse;
        }
        this.handleColumnSorting(this.sortField);
    } else {
        this.nanoTable.sortField = sortFiled;
        if (this.nanoTable.sortField === sortFiled) {
            this.nanoTable.sortInverse = !this.nanoTable.sortInverse;
        }
    }
    this.onPaginationChange();
}

private checkAreQueryParamsValid(): boolean {
    return Object.keys(this.getQueryParams()).includes('pageCount');
    // TODO: Fix this.
}

private filterListBySearchWord(): Array<any> {
    if (!this.searchWord) {
        return this._tableList;
    }
    let keys: Array<string> = Object.keys(this.tableList[0]);
    return this._tableList.filter((value: { [key: string]: string | number | null }) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            if (value[keys[i]] && value[keys[i]].toString().toLowerCase().includes(this.searchWord.toLowerCase())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    });
}

private getQueryParams(): Params {
    return this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams;
}

private handleColumnSorting(column: string): void {
    if (column === null) {
        return;
    }
    let compare = this.sortInverse ? compareReversed : compareNormal;

    function compareNormal(a, b) {
        if (a[column] === null) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (b[column] === null) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (a[column] < b[column]) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (a[column] > b[column]) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    function compareReversed(a, b) {
        if (a[column] === null) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (b[column] === null) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (a[column] > b[column]) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (a[column] < b[column]) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    this._tableList.sort(compare);
}

private onPaginationChange(): void {
    this.setQueryParams();
    if (this.isAsync) {
        this.isLoadingAsync = true;
        this.paginationChange.emit(this.nanoTable);
    }
}

private onTableListChange(): void {
    if (this.isAsync === true) {
        this.setTableParams();
    } else {
        this.setFromQueryParams();
        this.handleColumnSorting(this.sortField);
    }
}

private setFromQueryParams(): void {
    if (this.useQueryParams === true && this.checkAreQueryParamsValid()) {
        const queryParams = this.getQueryParams();
        this.pageCount = parseInt(queryParams['pageCount'], 10);
        this.pageNumber = parseInt(queryParams['pageNumber'], 10);
        this.sortField = queryParams['sortField'];
        this.sortInverse = queryParams['sortInverse'] === 'true';
    }
}
```

}

HTML part of table component:

```
div *ngIf="tableList.length > 0"
 class="nano-table-grid nano-mt-5">

<div class="nano-f-r">
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchWord" class="nano-white-smoke-input" placeholder="Search"/>
    <button *ngIf="hasExport === true && isExportInProgress === false"
            type="button"
            class="nano-f-250 nano-white-smoke-button nano-ml-2"
            (click)="exportReport()">
        <span>
            CSV
        </span>
    </button>
    <nano-loading-indicator *ngIf="isExportInProgress === true"
                            class="nano-loading-bar-small nano-loading-bar-overlay nano-f-250 "
                            style="margin-left: 2px"></nano-loading-indicator>
</div>

<div class="nano-table-row nano-table-grid-header">
    <div class="{{column.columnClass}}"
         *ngFor="let column of columnsArray"
         [ngClass]="{'sort-active':sortField === column.columnField}"
         (click)="onSortFieldChange(column.columnField)">
        <span>
            {{column.columnName}}
        </span>
        <i class="fa"
           [class.fa-sort-asc]="sortInverse === true && sortField === column.columnField"
           [class.fa-sort-desc]="sortInverse === false && sortField === column.columnField">
        </i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't the API have parameters where you can specify a range of pages? If it's always exactly 10 results, can you change this? If you don't have control over the API, how do you know you';ve reached the last audience in the collection?

Comment: Where you can get the number of pages?

Comment: @TheUnreal I don't know. In table in which I should present this data, by default is 10 items per page.

Comment: @Shilly I thing I dont have that api param on api on which I can specify range of pages. But I will check now.

Comment: @Shilly Is possible to change current implementation into that where I will iterate throught multiple page? 
Cus generally problem is that in this list of audience missing couple of audience.  And I research what can be the problem. I found that solution can be Iterating through APIs with multiple pages.

Comment: I don't know, it all depends on what the API you use offers you. What you describe is a simple loop or a parameter you have to add so it's perfectly possible, but without more info I don't know what the API can do or what changes have to be made to use the API. So unless you can link us the API documentation, we can't say which lines of code need changing. If it;s limited to 10 results per request, there HAS to be a parameter or other mechanism to paginate the data, else the API is broken. But if its `this.listUrl + '&page=4'` or `this.listURL + '&range=4-5'` is something only you can tell us.

Comment: @Shilly Ok thank you! Currently I don't have  to much informations, but you helped me here, to better understand what I need to do.

Comment: @Shilly ok thanks a lot! I need time to figure out.